# master theorem f(n) = nlogn

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, master-theorem

I am working Problem 4-3 from Introduction to Algorithm, 3rd Edition. And I am asked to find the asymptotic upper and lower bounds for T(n):

> T(n) = 4T(n/3) + n lg(n)

I have browsed online for the solution and the solution says:

> By master's theorem, we get T(n) ∈ Θ(n<sup>log<sub>3</sub>(4)</sup>)

I believe that the solution assumes that n<sup>log<sub>3</sub>4</sup> is asymptotically larger than n lg(n)? But why is this true? I will be grateful if someone can help me understand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In layman's terms:

We need to compare grow of `n*log(n)` with `n^1.25`    (`log3(4)~1.26`)

Divide both functions by n

```
  log(n) vs n^(1/4)
```

Both are increasing.
Derivatives of both functions

```
  n^(-1)  vs n^(-3/4)
```

Derivative of the second one is clearly larger, so the second function grows faster

[We can see](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x*ln(x)%20color%20blue%20and%20x%5E1.26%20color%20red%20for%20x%3D1..4000) that plots of these functions intersect and power function becomes larger for big n values - for **any** `power>1`